# android studio - facebook login stopped working

Tags: android, facebook

facebook login used to work just fine, now it stopped working.
there is a problem with onActivityResult.

in package com.facebook.login, class login manager,
onActivityResult, result code = -1 and data = null.

```
 boolean onActivityResult(int resultCode, Intent data,
 FacebookCallback<LoginResult>  callback) {}
```

i use
facebook-android-sdk:4.2.0

```
dependencies {
   ..
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.2.0'
 ..
}
```

Comment: what is the problem?

Comment: i tried it also with facebook-android-sdk:4.11.0.
and still the same problem.

Comment: the problem is the result code i am getting is -1